# What is 'LINKED RESOURCES' for on the new portal of windows azure?

Tags: azure

Without linking the database, the website is able to connect to the database.
Well then, when should I link the database to the website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linked Resources are a way of providing context to the portal about which Services belong to your deployed application. This enables the context for those service items to be added to your `publishsettings` file. The `publishsettings` file is used by [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio), [webmatrix](/questions/tagged/webmatrix) as well as the `Windows Azure CLI Tools` and `Windows Azure Powershell Tools` to import attributes of your subscription.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Linked Resource to [add](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-configure-websites/) a SQL Database database to your web site.

Comment: What would I add a SQL Database to my web site for? Just 'created' databases are able to be connected. http://www.rupan.net/uploader/download/1343710760.JPG

Comment: A "just created" database is a small MySQL database. You may want to use a larger SQL (Azure) Database

Comment: I think that a MySQL database is created when a new web site is created. http://www.rupan.net/uploader/download/1343716409.JPG  I'm sure the database what I created is a MS SQLServer database.