# Does setting SQL Azure rule "WINDOWS AZURE SERVICES"=YES mean anyone on azure can connect to my server?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In the SQL Azure management console when administering a Server you have an option to set the "allowed ip addresses" and also "allowed services". Within "allowed services" you can allow WINDOWS AZURE SERVICES but what does this mean exactly? Specifically, does this mean anyone else running a VM on Azure can connect to my server (assuming they know the username & password)? Or is there some other restriction like only azure services running within the same Subscription can connect, or only Linked Resources?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"WINDOWS AZURE SERVICES" means exactly what you suspect - anyone running any kind of service in Windows Azure (Azure WebSites, Azure Cloud Services/web/worker roles, Azure Virtual Machines) can access your SQL Database. But in order to really connect to your database, one must know **all** of:

- Name of your Windows Azure SQL Server (unique for you) (something like: **xxx99yyy**.database.windows.net)
- (Name of your Database to connect to)
- Login for the database
- Password for the database

Linked resources are only for visually help you organize all resources around a single application and [some other light stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732982/what-is-linked-resources-for-on-the-new-portal-of-windows-azure).

Comment: Thanks! I think your second bullet "Name of your Database to connect to" isn't right, as they could connect to master and select from sys.databases. 
Is there an MSDN reference that defines this or is it just implied by how they describe it?

Comment: ok, that is an exception. but for the Master one would need to know the Admin login/password, or custom db login with access rights to the master.

Comment: Absolutely, I'm just being picky and saying in order to connect they only need to know those 3 items, not those 4

Comment: that's why the name of the DB went into braces :)